# PBE AES_256 encryption incompatible between java 8 u65 and u71

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have some text encrypted and stored in a db using `PBE AES_256`. This was initially done using java `1.8.0_65`. After upgrading to latest java, I can no longer decrypt these fields. I have pinpointed the incompatibility to `1.8.0_71`. The release notes state the following:

> Problem with PBE algorithms using AES crypto corrected
>   An error was corrected for PBE using 256-bit AES ciphers such that the derived key may be different and not equivalent to keys previously derived from the same password.
>   JDK-8138589 (not public)

So I assume I need to migrate those field values 'manually', by decrypting with the old version, storing the plain value and subsequently re-encrypting with the current version. Is there a better way to do it or am I perhaps missing something regarding this incompatibility?

Here is part of the code that is used for encryption:

```
 SecretKey keyFromPassword =
        SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
            algorithm).generateSecret(
            new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray()));

 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyFromPassword, new PBEParameterSpec(
        salt, iterations, new IvParameterSpec(iv)));
 IOUtils.copyLarge(new CipherInputStream(clearStream, cipher), encryptedStream);
```

**Solution**
I was able to decrypt the existing values by doing some reflection magic on my cipher and re-initializing it. Here is the code if anyone is interested:

```
Object spi = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(cipher, "spi");
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(spi, "keyLength", 128);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyFromPassword, new PBEParameterSpec(
        salt, iterations, new IvParameterSpec(iv)));
```

Comment: it would be better if you post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrating the field values sounds like a reasonable approach.

Looking at the [actual code change](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/rev/5ea62bb625b6) related to [JDK-8138589](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1298949) does not look too complicated.

The difference seems to be just the key length. Therefore you should be able to reproduce the old value even on versions after 1.8.0_71.

In case you detect an an value created with an old Java version but now running on a "new"  Java version you could migrate it. A successful migration is indicated by and additional field that is saved.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how to reproduce the old value on version 71+.  Can I manually set the keyLength in the `PBEParameterSpec`?

Comment: You have not provided the code how you encrypt therefore I don't know what code you are using. I assume you have to manually generate the key and the en/decrypt. See [PBES2Core.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5ea62bb625b6/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBES2Core.java) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I am already looking at it. I will also provide a code snippet in the original question.